# In how many ways can six people be seated in a circle with ten seats?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm having troubles with solving this question:

> We have 6 people. In how many ways we can put them in a line?

-The answer is $720$, because $6!=720$.

> We want to put them in circle with 6 seats.

-The answer is $5!=120$.

> In circle with $10$ seats?

-The answer is $15120$, but I can't figure it out why is that so.

Comment: @kimiTanaka  The OP understands that.  See his answer to the second question.  The issue is how to handle the four empty seats.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in circular arrangements, there is *no sense of first and last*. **But** if you put one person on any seat on circular table, he can be used as a *marker of beginning/end*. Thus this circular arrangement can be treated as a linear arrangement now!

For **second** problem: We put a person on any seat. Now only 5 people are left to put on 5 seats. This can be done in $5!$ ways.

For the **third** problem: If you want to put in circle with 10 seats, then first put 1 person on any seat. Now, you have 5 persons to put on 9 seats, So the answer is $\binom{9}{5} \cdot 5!$

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but i still don't understand why is there 9C5

Comment: You have put $1$ person at a seat. Call him $P$. Now we can think of this as now this has converted into linear arrangement where $P$ is always at front, ie his position is fixed. You have $9$ seats and $5$ persons remaining. Choose $5$ seats from $9$, and then arrange persons among themselves.

Comment: Oh, nice.. Than you very much, now I clearly understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the circle there is no way to tell who is first. Put someone in the circle and then fill in the remaining 5. How we fill in those 5 is what matters.

For the circle with 10 spots, think of it like the circle with 6 spots, but now with 4 indistinguishable people. That is, there is no difference between one empty seat and another. The only difference comes from the people around them.